# Unable to initialize a function returning pointer to a structure

Tags: c++

I am relatively new to programming, so please pardon me as this is a very simple and basic question. I am working in visual studio 2019. I made a class Sphere and inside it I created a structure:

```
struct point{

vec3 coordinate; //I am using glm library

};
struct triangle{

point p1, p2, p3;

};
```

Now when I declare a function returning a pointer to struct triangle:

```
// in the .h file
triangle* returnTriangle(triangle T);

//--------------------------------------------------------

//and later in the .cpp file
triangle* Sphere:: returnTriangle(triangle T) //This definition was made by the IDE itself.
{
         //code returning a triangle* variable
}
```

I get an error:

Identifier triangle is undefined.
Declaration is incompatible with Sphere::returnTriangle();

I get this error only for the triangle used in the function definition that is if I use triangle inside the function, it doesn't show this error.

I have included the Sphere.h file in Sphere.cpp, so why is triangle still undefined?

**EDIT:**

The complete error message:

E0020 identifier triangle is undefined.

//The line of function definition that is triangle* //Sphere::returnTriangle(triangle T)
//{code}

E0147 declaration is incompatible with Sphere::triangle* Sphere::print

Minimum reproducable example:
just make a class and create a structure (say triangle) you wish. Then declare a function inside the class:

```
triangle* print();
```

Then define the function in the .h file:

```
triangle* Sphere::print()
{
      //some code
}
```

Comment: [mcve] and full error message.

Comment: try to define the struct outside of the class in .h file. that might be the reason

Comment: As pointed out by Aysu. Another solution might to use Sphere::triangle* to the return type in the source file

Comment: Yeah both of the suggestions solve my problem! ...but I am interested to know why is it that I don't have to write Sphere::triangle when using triangle inside the function.

Comment: @super I have posted the minimal reproducible example and complete error message.

Comment: If you declare `struct triangle` in the scope of `class Sphere`, the full name is `Sphere::triangle`. Your `print` declaration is also in the scope of `class Sphere`, so there you can just use `triangle` as it is already in the `Sphere` namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will sum it up:

It you defined an inner-struct `triangle` (you should call it `Triangle` by the way!). In order to call it from ***outside the class*** you must specify its complete name, thus, the following signature is not valid:

```
Triangle* Sphere::returnTriangle(Triangle T)
```

Because it is looking for a struct with a name `Triangle`, but there is **no** struct with this name. The struct is called `Sphere::Triangle` which isn't the same as `Triangle`.

When you are inside a context of the class (for example, when writing the body of member method), you don't need to specify the location, since in this context, `Sphere` is included in "namespaces" which the compiler "knows", and you don't need to explicitly tell it to look inside of the `Sphere` class.

This behavior is similar to `namespace`. This is a tool to distinguish between different signatures. For example, STL has an implementation of `vector`, but assume that we want to write a new implementation of `vector`. We can do so by declaring this class in our namespace, and we get two different signatures:

```
std::vector
```

vs:

```
our_namespace::vector
```

and these are not the same!